# SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out with NGINX configuration

Tags: java, sockets, nginx, timeout

I have the following setup:

`curl >> NGINX >> Java Client >> ELB >> NGINX >> Java Server`

Regular requets work as expected, requests over 60s fail with a `SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. I tried to debug step by step:

- Server responds with **200** and takes around 100s
- Nginx in front of the server logs **499** (client stopped connection)
- Java Client and the Nginx log **400**: SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

I tried reducing the `proxy_read_limit` of both Nginx which led to a `504 Gateway timeout`. The ELB a limit of 240 seconds.

I don't have access to the Client application as it is a .jar, is it safe to assume the problem is a timeout setting within the .jar and thus I can't solve the issue on my own?
Also I have trouble understanding who exactly is the client in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does sound like the timeout setting within "Java Client" is set to less than 100s. If the client is well written, you may be able to change the timeout parameter through parameters or config files. It's impossible to say more without knowing the details.

You *may* be able to work around the problem by making the server send "dummy" packets that makes the connection appear active to the client.